# Dialog Box not open with GET_FILE_NAME Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have oracle database 11g with oracle forms and reports 11g. I created browse button to open CSV File from computer or laptop directory

[image]

I am using this code on trigger when-button-press:

```
declare
 filename varchar2(500);
begin
 filename := GET_FILE_NAME(File_Filter=> ‘CSV Files
 (*.Csv)|*.Csv|’);
:block2.FILE_NAME:= filename;

end;
```

When I pressed the button then did not open dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

*Your code works on `Forms 6i` provided you have properly attached the `.olb`  and `.pll` files for `webutil`, but for `Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g` the method `GET_FILE_NAME` should be replaced with `CLIENT_GET_FILE_NAME` to search in your local file system instead of application server as below :*

`:block2.FILE_NAME := CLIENT_GET_FILE_NAME(File_Filter=> 'CSV Files (*.Csv)|*.Csv|');`

Comment: identifier 'client_get_file_name' must be declared

Comment: @RamizTariq are you sure that you added `webutil.pll` under `Attached Libraries` node and dragged `webutil.olb` into `Object Groups` node ..? `webutil.pll` has a method called `client_get_file_name`.

Comment: Not attached. Any other way to attach csv file with browse button without using webutil?

Comment: @RamizTariq I don't know and I don't think if any other way exists, but I suggest you add and use webutil.

Comment: I attached webutil.pll and webutil.olb. After attached when I pressed the button then getting error WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled exception

Comment: @RamizTariq if you're invoking form from application server, then you need to choose `Yes` option during attaching webutil.pll whenever `Remove path?` question is prompted.

Comment: I am using oracle forms on laptop. During attaching webutil.pll i selected "No" for path

Comment: @RamizTariq anyway you need an application server( webutil ) even if located in your local machine, you need to deploy you .fmb file to that app server, since `client_get_file_name` is such a feature which is used by invoking through web based logic instead of client-server logic.

Comment: I configured webutil from this link http://dbperfection.com/webutil-configuration-steps-for-oracle-fusion-middleware-forms-11g-r2/.  Now I am getting this error: frm-40734 internal error pl/sql error occurred after press button

Comment: @RamizTariq please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445941/oracle-form-freezes-after-configure-webutil/53907574#53907574) related to **setting %CLASSPATH% and missing jar files**