# Browse and File Open in ORACLE 10g using forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Iam using Oracle 10g application developer

I used the following code in 6i and it works

```
DECLARE
  filename VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
  filename := GET_FILE_NAME(File_Filter=> 'DOC Files (*.doc)|*.doc|');
end;
```

But the same is not working in 10g .Please help

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to see the picture you attached but I suppose tihs is the same problem with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140696/dialog-box-not-open-with-get-file-name-oracle-forms/55149706#55149706)

Comment: The same problem is mentioned in the link  but there is no solution,

Comment: version `6` was client-server based, whereas `10` is not. You have an extra tier(`application server`) for this.So the proper configuration for app. server and adding `.olb` and `.pll` for `webutil` is needed. As a starting point, Are you sure that you remove the path during the attachment of `webutil.pll` library ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Barbaros, you'll have to use Webutil to access client tiers (cause after 6i you have the application server layer, you are no more in client-server mode).
Check the client_get_file_name procedure from the webutil package, there is lot of documentation available on how to use webutil but that's another subject.